# How to use google calendar api credentials

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, google-calendar-api

I am using google calendar in ASP.NET MVC , I have placed client_secret.json file at root folder just like web.config file .

When I am browsing the application from internet or mobile browser to connect google calendar it is throwing an error like

```
unable to found the client_secret.json.
```

Whenever I'm using that from Azure VM, it is working fine, after I ran that application internet or mobile browser it is working fine. Below is the code which I used to connect google calendar, can you please check the below code and suggest what I am doing wrong here.

```
UserCredential credential;
using (var stream = new FileStream(@"D:\Connectgoogle\client_secret.json"
                                   , FileMode.Open
                                   , FileAccess.Read))
{
    credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
        GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
        new[] { CalendarService.Scope.Calendar },
        "LookIAmAUniqueUser",
        CancellationToken.None,
        new FileDataStore(@"c:\datastore", true)
    ).Result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here is the directory of the client_secret.json, this part in your code:

```
using (var stream = new FileStream(@"D:\Connectgoogle\client_secret.json"
                                   , FileMode.Open
                                   , FileAccess.Read))
```

If you follow the [.NET Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/dotnet), you just move the client_secret.json inside your working directory:

> a. Drag client_secret.json (downloaded in Step 1) into your Visual
>   Studio Solution Explorer.

and your program will be the one to locate it like:

```
using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
```

Check the quickstart link for the full code implementation.